# LabVIEW holds Excel Reference

Tags: excel, reference, labview

I try to open and excel reference in LabVIEW and then close it after sometime. But the LabVIEW keeps holding the reference and does not release it unless I close the VI. Why is this happening? Is there anyway to force it to release the Reference?

I am checking the error out for any errors. But it is not throwing up any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you doing in Excel?

Typically, Labview will hold the reference open only until it is closed.  However, this includes any references to *any* part of excel (excel.worksheet, excel.range, excel.workbook, etc).  You need to close each reference explicitly.

It can be painstaking to debug, but you need to manually go through your entire excel-handling section and make sure that every reference is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking the return value from the close file command? I've had this problem with LV in the past and have found this to be one possible root cause for this problem.

Check out the following example file to see if you are doing things the same way:

labview\examples\file\datalog.llb\Read Datalog File Example.vi

HTH